# CakePHP 1.3 Media Views results in corrupted file when downloading

Tags: cakephp-1.3, download

I am starting with CakePHP. After a document has been uploaded to my server then the user tries to download it, but the file results corrupt.

What may be causing this to happen? I checked the file through my website's cPanel and it is perfect. This problem only occurs when the user tries to download it.

In my Requirement controller:

```
function download() {
    $file = //here I get the file
    $loca = //here I get its location

    if (!empty ($file)) {
        $file_info = pathinfo($file);

        $this->view = 'Media'; 
        $params = array( 
            'id'        => $file,
            'name'      => $file,
            'extension' => $file_info['extension'], 
            'download'  => true, 
            'path'      => APP . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . $loca . DS
       );
       $this->set($params);
   } else {
       $this->redirect($this->referer());
   }
}
```

And in my view:

```
echo $html->link(
    'Download', array(
        'controller' => 'requirements', 
        'action'     => 'download'
    )
);
```

I have been trying to solve this for a long time. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

hmm im not really sure about this is the problem... but the doc about the [Media Views](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1094/Media-Views) says:

> **name -** The name allows you to specify an alternate file name to be sent to the user. Specify the name **without** the file extension.

and you are not adding the mime type neither... try adding it

Good Luck

Comment: I tried both. The name without extension and the mimeType. But when I download any file, it results corrupt. For example when I download a pdf and then open it to see its content there's a dialog that says: "Adobe Reader couldn't open <my_file.pdf> because it is not a correct file or it is corrupt(e.g. was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decodified)". It works perfectly locally, with any kind of files, but not on the host provider. Any help please? I do not know what to do?

Comment: my guess is that there's something wrong in the code and its sending an error message that it's being downloaded as a pdf file. Try this: run your code and download a pdf file "for example" then try to open it with the notepad or any text editor, probably you'll see html code with an error message.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Thank you pleasedontbelong. In Notepad++ I can see "set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons". Then I did a phpinfo(); and in the "disable_functions" section, indeed set_time_limit() is disabled. Could this be the cause of the error? What can I do?

Comment: well.. at least you found the error message =) set_time_limit() require safe_mode=off in php.ini, so if you can, change your php.ini settings

Answer (score 0):

The media plugin does not work if your setting in core.php for debug is set to anything but 0. Probably has something to do with the rendering of view which if set for debug mode is different.